# how set main menu bar such that in its view in middle in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

[image]http://postimg.org/image/fi1bwpfoz/   How to show menu Bar without internal frame in java swing .i have use internal frame for displaying menu bar.whats should be an alternate slution for that.

[image]

here is my code
 private void jLabel3FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    try {

        //String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass = "paras123";

       //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Driver d=new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from employee");

        while (rs.next()) {

            int col = rs.getInt("id");
            String first_name = rs.getString("firstname");
            String last_name = rs.getString("lastname");
            String job = rs.getString("job_title");
            //String p=col+""+first_name+""+last_name+""+job;
            System.out.println(col + " " + first_name + " " + last_name + " " + job);

        }

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        //err.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }





    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menu3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new menu3().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu10;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu11;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu12;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu13;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu14;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu15;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu16;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu6;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu7;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu8;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu9;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem5;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem6;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem7;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem8;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: but it should shift on top of frame.is there any alternative that it would be like as similar as snapshot view.

Comment: What are you talking about? You mean you want to add space to the top without using the internal frame?

Comment: *"whats should be an alternate slution for that"* - You could start by reading through the [available tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).  Don't forget, a `JMenuBar` is just another component...

Comment: how to position menu bar to middle  of frame. if donot use internal frame it would move on top of frame. please  help

Comment: how could i do with netbeans designer there is  horizontal and vertical properties in netbeans  and  no position  .  north and south in that

Comment: how to use netbeans designer to align menu bar noth

Comment: please help me its urgent

Comment: how could  i use menu  bar on focus of label and without internal frame in swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't go wrong using the BorderLayout to set the menu bar at the top regardless the resizing of the window and all. hope this helps.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Test");
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("test2");
menu.add(item);
menuBar.add(menu);
frame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Why not `setJMenuBar()`?

Comment: i want that my title and label would be above menu bar.that why iahve used menu bar in internal frame. as i know menu bar should acts component would be top of frame. any idead how set similar layout without internal frame in swing

Comment: then try using another jpanel just for the menubar. set its layout to borderlayout and add the menubar into that jpanel.

Comment: setJMenuBar() should work too, didn't think of that haha

Comment: we cannot add menu  bar in panel